# NewRelic add-on on Heroku with a custom rails environment

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I have added the standard newrelic add-on to my Rails 3.2 app running on Heroku. 
The RACK_ENV for my app is called staging2. I added newrelic.yml file to the `config`
directory. I updated the file to add a new section called staging2 to the yml file.

```
staging2:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
```

After deployment I accessed the NewRelic UI. I am shown the message below:

```
Welcome, ! Thanks for taking advantage of our partnership with heroku.
Set up your app!
```

I am assuming NewRelic is not detecting my app because of the custom RAILS_ENV name. How do I get round this issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting RACK_ENV to `production` to determine whether that's the cause?

Comment: Yes. I have set `RAILS_ENV` and `RACK_ENV`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to an error from my end, I didn't added the `newrelic_rpm` gem to the `Gemfile`. 
In the past when I used `newrelic` with Rails 2.x, I didn't add the gem to the Gemfile.

The problem went away after adding the gem.